# DataGrid disable editing of data

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid

```
DataGrid Margin="0 10 0 0" x:Name="VideoAudioCombinationDataGrid" HorizontalAlignment="Left" 
                   GridLinesVisibility="None" BorderBrush="Transparent" Background="Transparent" 
                   ColumnHeaderStyle="{StaticResource g8_MergeColumnHeaderStyle}" AutoGenerateColumns="False"
    DataGrid.Columns
    DataGridTextColumn   CellStyle="{StaticResource g8_mergecolumnStyle}" Foreground="#FFC7CFD2" Header="Videos" Width="250" CanUserResize="True"  Binding="{Binding Video}"
    DataGridTextColumn CellStyle="{StaticResource g8_mergecolumnStyle}" Foreground="#FFC7CFD2" Header="Audios"  Width="250"   CanUserResize="True"  Binding="{Binding Audio}"
    DataGridTemplateColumn Header="" CanUserResize="False
    DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate
    DataTemplate
        Button Content="Delete" 
                        Command="Delete"
    /DataTemplate
    /DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate
    /DataGridTemplateColumn
    /DataGrid.Columns
/DataGrid
```

I am binding an observable collection to my datagrid.
It works fine but suppose i have 10 elements in my observable collection ,here total 11 rows are coming . Suppose i put IsReadOnly property of datagrid to false, it solves this issue. But then i can't delete items from datagrid. Plz help. Please help me in deleting this extra row coming in my datagrid.

Comment: It looks like WPF xml.. Perhaps there are properties `AllowEdit` and `AllowDelete`, by using which you can selectively disable only editing (while `ReadOnly` makes everything off).

Comment: AllowEdit is not available with WPF DataGrid

Comment: Then, as I see it, you have to extend `DataGrid` to react on something (to example on Delete key) and in the event delete currently selected item manually.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply set 'CanUSerAddRows' and 'CanUserDeleteRows' on DataGrid to false and true resp.